# Database connection with Mongooose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When using `createconnection()` instead of `connect()` in  Mongoose, my query become hanged in postman it is showing socket hang up.

I want to know the difference between `createconnection()` and `connect()` in Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

Basic difference is that `connect` creates a default connection while `createConnection` creates a separate connection so that way you can create and use multiple connection at the same time. See [Multiple connection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections)

As of `hung up` part of your question we need a code where you create connection, register a schema and create a model and of course a route handler itself.